# Issue on Bootstrap Dropdown List Hover Higlight

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add image/Icon to bootstrap dropdown btn list options [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/AvXPU/)
It works somehow but as you can see from the demo and following image the hover function does not reacting (highlighting)on the whole li area!

[image]

Can you please let me know how to fix this highlits all width of the li element?

Here is my code as well
CSS:

```
li.one {
background-image: url("http://i1275.photobucket.com/albums/y443/Behseini/lister_zps15367983.png") !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 5px 7px;
width: 60px;
height: 25px;
}
```

and the HTML

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button class="btn span2">Select</button>
<button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="one"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="two"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="three"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li class="four"><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li class="five"><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    <li class="six"><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using list item background as an icon is a bad idea since it makes laying on the text really tricky (as you experienced).

I'd definitely encourage you to add a new, separate element for the icons. [By convention, icons are added in bootstrap in format](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons) `<i class="icon-[name]"></i>`. If you want custom icons, you can of course define your own classes and related CSS styles.

Here's a quick example:

HTML:

```
<li class="one"><a href="#"><i class="icon-custom-1"></i>Item 1</a>
```

CSS:

```
.icon-custom-1 {
    background-image: url("http://i1275.photobucket.com/albums/y443/Behseini/lister_zps15367983.png") !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 7px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

On a related note, you can wildcard all icon-* styles so you don't have to copy&paste the same stuff everywhere:

```
div[class*='icon-custom-'] {
    /* Insert common CSS styles here */
}
```

Note that I'm using extra `custom-` to separate this custom icon formatting from icons provided natively by bootstrap.

Happy bootstrapping!

Comment: Hi jsalonen , Thanks it is working now bout how about the aligning li text and .icon-1 class? as you can see from the demo they are not horizontally aligned. can you please let me know how to fix it?

Comment: Using @jsalonen fiddle above, you can change the background-position to:
        background-position: 0px 0px; 

But you may need to play with your height as well as you appear to be using a sprite.

Comment: Thanks @BJack, thanks but the problem is I can't change the height of the image! I need to keep them in 25px;

Comment: You don't need to adjust the image's height, but the list item's height. Try background-position: 0px 0px; and height: 19px; I think that the core code from Bootstrap has some li padding/margins already which is why the height seems like an odd number.

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply looking to have the highlight extend to the right when hovered I would suggest removing the width: 60px; from each of your li.one, li.two etc.

Maybe add some extra margin on your li a selector as well to reduce the overlap.

Overall I would agree with jsalonen that you should look into utilizing the built-in icon code in Bootstrap.